# pydantic nested model response

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I want to pass nested models into the response. I am trying by making object of 1 model then storing the related values to it, making object of 2nd model and storing related values to it and at the last trying to store thoes 2 model in the response model. Can you guys please help me out. Thank you

**Models**

```
class SetImageSetInput(BaseModel):
  profileId: str
  
  class Config:
    orm_mode = True



class ValidateFaceAlignmentInput(BaseModel):
  currentFrame: str
  
  class Config:
    orm_mode = True

class outputResponse(BaseModel):
    response1: ValidateFaceAlignmentInput
    response2: SetImageSetInput


SetImageSetInput.profileId="pic1"
ValidateFaceAlignmentInput.currentFrame="1"
outputResponse.response1 = SetImageSetInput
outputResponse.response2 = ValidateFaceAlignmentInput

return SetImageSetInput
```

But I am getting error while executing this api

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for outputResponse
response -> response1
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create instances of the corresponding classes and pass those to your reponse model object in the constructor. In code, it should read like

```py
response = outputResponse(
    response1= ValidateFaceAlignmentInput(currentFrame ='1'), 
    response2=SetImageSetInput(profileId ='pic1'), 
)
return response
```

Comment: Sorry, had a typo. Can you try it again. It works here.